# Android menu item define style for enabled/disabled status

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

Is it possible to define different style for menu item depending on its enabled/disabled status?

For example, I want the text color of menu item to be gray in disabled mode and white in enabled mode.

I didn't have success with changing color dinamycally just as many people didn't on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5):

It really depends on the item you wish to customize.

Basically you can create a custom color that changes depending on its state:

**colors/custom_color.xml:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#FF0000" android:state_enabled="false"  />
    <item android:color="#CCCCCC"/>
</selector>
```

Then set it to your menu item like this:

```
menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView().
        setBackgroundResource(R.colors/custom_color.xml);
```

Or perhaps in the xml if available:

```
android:textColor="@color/custom_color"
```

Comment: I'm unable to do this because getActionView() returns null

Comment: @user3199693 please post the code of your menu.xml file. More specifically we need the menu item's code which you are trying to customize.

Comment: I only have one menu item which consists of id and text. Nothing special. textColor attribute is not accessible.

Comment: @user3199693 you can create your own custom layout and apply it to the  menu item with `setActionView()`. Then you can either set it programatically or through the layout's xml that you've used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a drawable as the text colour, and in drawable you can use selector to select the colour according to enabled status. Using following drawable definition as colour will make your disabled menu items grey and the rest black.

```
In e.g. res/drawable/default_text_colour.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/white"/>
</selector>
```

Then, using the drawable:

```
<item name="android:textColor">@drawable/default_text_colour</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

For some one else may be needed: use ToolBar instead of ActionBar, add TextView and set style as MenuItem:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_explorer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBar.Theme"
        android:background="@mipmap/bg_naviber">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/title_activity_explorer2"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:padding="@dimen/dimen_8"
            style="@style/CustomActionBar.Tittle"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:text="@string/action_delete"
            android:textColor="@drawable/selector_text_view"
            android:padding="@dimen/dimen_16"
            style="@style/CustomActionBar.Menu"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_do_delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:text="@string/action_do_delete"
            android:textColor="@drawable/selector_text_view"
            android:padding="@dimen/dimen_16"
            style="@style/CustomActionBar.Menu"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

set textColor by selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <!-- order is important -->
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/white_disabled"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/white"/>
    <item android:color="@color/white"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
<style name="Theme.WordsTrainer" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
```

I've added the line:

```
<item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
```

to themes.xml and night\themes.xml, and this works fine with day and nigth mode both.

I've spend a day diggin it, and finally found the answer in obvious place:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme